# Port scanning from localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, tcp, netstat

I see lot of tcp connections on different ports on my server with 'TIME_WAIT' status.
Just simple port scan, but i cant see ip address of this bastard because connections is going from my nginx.
Can you please give me a tip how can i see IP address of this bastard?

Here is example:

```
[root@vh9 ~]# netstat
tcp        0      0 srv:http                    srv:53280                   TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 srv:http                    srv:53536                   TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 srv:http                    srv:52768                   TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 srv:http                    srv:53024                   TIME_WAIT
```

Answer (score 7):

This is not a port scan, it's perfectly valid connections from your nginx to apache backend.

Comment: No, i haven't any services on this ports.
My backend running on 127.0.0.1:80

Comment: These are source ports, they are expected to be random. They are listed in the "Foreign Address" column just because you are looking at backend's side of connections.

Comment: Hmm, that can be true :)